# How can I find out Blade server hardware model from XenCenter

Tags: hardware, xen

We have a XenServer pool with 3 blade servers, I want to find out the hardware model of these blades and figure out if I can install more RAMs.

I don't have physical access but I do know the root password and I also have XenCenter installed.

Looked around, I can see how much RAM installed but I can't find out information like, how many free memory slot left and what is the max amount of RAM supported by these Blades.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

XenServer userland is in CentOS. You can use dmidecode for this info.

```
# dmidecode -t system | grep Product
    Product Name: (your motherboard model here)

# dmidecode -t memory | grep Size
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 8192 MB
    Size: 16 MB
```

The 16MB is a flash. The rest are RAM. You can remove the grep to see the full output of the memory which will show you the rest of the information you need.